# Загрузка изображений из сети в ListView

Tags: android, json

Здравствуйте. Имеется файл в JSON формате. В нем дан массив объектов, каждый объект содержит поле "name" и поле "image", в котором указан url для загрузки картинки. Я хочу вывести в ListView имя объекта и изображение. Для этого я использую класс ImageManadger из [данной](http://habrahabr.ru/post/78747/) статьи.
Пробовал разные способы, однако ничего не получается. Огромная просьба показать, каким образом мне можно загрузить изображения из файла в ListView.
Заранее спасибо

```
try {
            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(result);

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            HashMap<String, Object> map;

            for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("name", c.getString("name"));
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                ImageManager.fetchImage(c.getString("image"), imgView);
                imgView.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmap = imgView.getDrawingCache();
                d = new BitmapDrawable(bmap);
                map.put("image",d);
                map.put("image2",c.getString("image"));
                MyArrList.add(map);

            }

            SimpleAdapter simpleadapter;
            simpleadapter = new SimpleAdapter(SecondActivity.this, MyArrList,
                    R.layout.list, new String[] { "name", "image"}, new int[] { R.id.myName, R.id.imageView1});
            listView.setAdapter(simpleadapter);




        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут совсем все плохо.
 1. Загрузка всех картинок в цикле и складирование их в словарь - вылетит с outofmemory на слабых устройтсвах.
 2. Работа в главном потоке - плохо.
Мой совет - использовать отличную библиотеку [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Далее наследуетесь от SimpleAdapter и в методе getView(...) пишете:

```
Picasso.with(context)
      .load(url)
      .into((ImageView)view.findViewByID(R.id.imageView1));
```

А загрузку в цикле убираете вообще.

Comment: Есть также [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) там и кэш на диск и в память и куча всего дополнительного.

Comment: Ну мне показалась UIL слишком навороченной, пикассо работает без лишних наворотов и тоже может использовать кэш в память и на диск. Сам гугл советует использовать Volley https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley для сетевых запросов включая получение картинок.